# New laptop crashes with bug check after hibernate

Tags: windows-8.1, crash, bsod, hibernate, hyper-v

About once a week my laptop crashes with a bugcheck 9F when restoring from hibernate.

I have examined the dumps with windbg and they all seem related to hyper-V

The FAULTING_MODULE is always `vmswitch` and the bugcheck analysis looks like

> DRIVER_POWER_STATE_FAILURE (9f) A driver has failed to complete a power IRP within a specific time.
>   Arguments:
>   Arg1: 0000000000000003, A device object has been blocking an Irp for too long a time
>   Arg2: ffffe0000061cb70, Physical Device Object of the stack
>   Arg3: fffff80105328840, nt!TRIAGE_9F_POWER on Win7 and higher, otherwise the Functional  Device Object of the stack
>   Arg4: ffffe0000bac02c0, The blocked IRP

I sometimes use Hyper-V but no VMs are running when the computer is hibernated.

The Dell laptop runs Windows 8.1 and all updates are installed.

I can live with a crash once a week but if there is a simple solution I'd like to try it.

Comment: Do all installed drivers have specific Windows 8.1 support?

Comment: Slap the minidump into WinDbg and fire away. The "faulting module" is sometimes misleading.

Comment: Post the full output of the `!analyze -v` and `lmv` commands.

Comment: upload the dmp files

Comment: @Ramhound, No, the wireless adapter driver states windows 8 but it is the latest available.

Comment: where is the link t the dump?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess would be it's related to your network adapter drivers and their power management.

Go download and install the latest drivers for your network adapter; preferably the ones offered by the NIC manufacturer, not Dell or Microsoft.

If that still doesn't help (or you have the latest already) then head to the configuration of the network adapter (hardware) and under the Power Management tab *disable* "Allow the computer to turn off this device to save power", and see how it goes.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I'll try this and see if it makes a difference.

Comment: I have not had any crashes the last couple of weeks so this seem to be the solution. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

**I would like to say that I do not work for IO Bit.**  I have found that a number of problems I had with my PC were due to me searching for drivers and installing them. Even though I was not careless about installing the drivers for my hardware I presumably installed the wrong drivers.

The IOBit Driver Booster resolved many if not all of the problems I had.